# How do I center a div ontop of another div that has inline block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a `text` div on top of `box` div that has `inline block`. I tried using `position: absolute` on the text div. But when the browser screen is shrunk or expanded, the positioning of the `text` div gets messed up. How to fix this?

```css
.mainDiv {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the blue `div` to be always on top *(and centered)* of the red `div`, regardless of where the red `div` might go?

Comment: Yes, Blue div(text) to be on top of the red box. If I shrink/expand the window, the text has to still be in the center of the red box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using inline-block to center the `.box` inside the `.main-div`. Technically, with your current html structure you can't center the `.text` element on the `.box` one, but you can center it on `.main-div`, which is essentially the same thing in your example.

I would start by adding `position: relative` to `.main-div`. An absolutely positioned element is positioned based on it's nearest ancestor that has a positioning context. The easiest way to set this is to add `position: relative`.

Then with your `.text` element you can adjust to:

```
.text {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50% );
}
```

This works because `top` and `left` position the top and left element from the top and left of its parent. So the top of `.text` would start 50% of the way down `.main-div`, and likewise with left. This would leave your text too far down and to the left.

`transform: translate` values work differently - they are based on the size of the element itself. So `-50%` will move an element back half of its width or height. By setting it on both width and height we are moving the `.text` so that instead of its top and left edges being at 50%, it's center is at 50%.

```css
.mainDiv {
  position: relative; /* added to make .text align relative to this, not the document */
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  /* left: 300px; (I removed this for demo purposes, but if you need it you can add it back in) */
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50% ); /*pull the text left and up 50% of the text's size*/
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to post a snippet. By ontop this is what I understood

Comment: I liked all the answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The markup for text should be written first then the box. Then you may try using `block` instead of `inline-block`, then set the width of the text to 100 percent, display `block` and 'margin: 0 auto'. Also, maybe consider using the appropriate semantic tags as opposed to divs if you can. Also, I suspect the `top` and `left` rules to be causing the text to not align properly. You should no longer need `position:absolute` either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can make the blue `div` a child of the red `div` so that the blue `div` will always be relative to the red `div`. I also added `position:relative` to the red `div`, and used `transform:translate` to the blue `div`.

If I'm not mistaken, this is also responsive, so try shrinking your browser.

```css
.mainDiv {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.text {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mainDiv {
text-align: center;
}

.box {
background-color: red;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 19px;
}

.text {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -19px 0 0 36px;
}

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="box">
  <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
</div>
```